# Navigation Arch Component: Passing placeholder param for deeplink

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to implement a deeplink functionality using the new Navigation Component API v1.0.0-alpha05 but running into an issue.

Using Android Studio 3.3 Canary 7

Portion of my navigation_graph.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/noteDetailFragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.notes.notedetail.NoteDetailFragment"
    android:label="@string/label_note_detail"
    tools:layout="@layout/note_detail_fragment">

    <argument
        android:name="noteId"
        android:defaultValue="0"
        app:argType="integer" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_noteDetail_to_editNote"
        app:destination="@id/editNoteFragment" />

    <deepLink
        android:id="@+id/noteDetailDeepLink"
        app:uri="notesapp://notes/{noteId}" />
</fragment>
```

AndroidManifest.xml contains:

```
    <activity android:name=".presentation.MainActivity">
        <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/navigation_graph" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am testing my deeplink with `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "notesapp://notes/2" com.myapp.notes`

The `noteId` is not present in either `NoteDetailFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments).noteId` or `arguments?.getInt("noteId", 0)` (a default value of `0` is returned in both cases)

Printing out the Bundle shows that it is there:

`[{android-support-nav:controller:deepLinkIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=notesapp://notes/2 flg=0x1000c000 pkg=com.mynotes.notes cmp=com.mynotes.notes.presentation.MainActivity }, noteId=2}]`

The same issue is observed if the deeplink uri is  `http://www.mynotes.com/notes/2`

How do I access the `noteId` when deeplinking? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110273284), arguments parsed from deep links are only added to the `arguments` Bundle as Strings.

Therefore you should retrieve the noteId via `arguments?.getString("noteId")?.toInt()` until that issue is fixed.

Comment: Thanks, Ian! The workaround works well and I will be watching release notes. P. S. I enjoyed your Android Developers Backstage podcast, btw.

Comment: You can also hit the Star in the upper left corner of the issue to get updates on when it is fixed. Thanks for the kind words :)

Comment: Observing a related issue. Let me know if it's something that I can add to the ticket above. Once I process a deeplink with `arguments?.getString("noteId")?.toInt()`, what used to work for non-deeplink access (`fromBundle(arguments).noteId`) stops working ( default 0 is returned). I am seeing this in the same app session where I detect deeplink to handle it differently.

Comment: Not sure what could cause that, but a sample project attached to that issue that shows your issue would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: I will clean the project up and add to the ticket

Comment: @liminal for now use Elvis operator (?:) until the issue is fixed
`arguments?.getString("noteId")?.toInt() ?: fromBundle(arguments).noteId`

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed in android.arch.navigation 1.0.0-alpha09.

> Bug Fixes
>
> Arguments are now properly parsed from deep links as the correct argType instead of always as strings [b/110273284](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110273284)

Arch Components Release notes: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes

Answer (score 0):

The Android Navigation Library will **always** parse placeholder parameters as strings unless the type is explicitly declared in the Nav Graph as an argument.

For a placeholder of `{noteId}`, receive the passed parameter as an Integer by declaring the argument as an integer.

```
<argument
    android:name="id"
    app:argType="integer"
    android:defaultValue="0" />
```